# share a state across multiple elements in a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of elements that are drawn on a canvas.

```
export function useCanvas(){
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [ elements, setElements] = useState([]);
    const [ isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvasObj = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvasObj.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        elements.forEach(element => {
          drawElements (ctx, element);
          hoveredElement(ctx, mouseOver, element, setIsHover);
        });
    });
}
```

What my issue is, is with `isHover`. When I call the `hoveredElement(ctx, mouseOver, element, setIsHover);` on each elements, I'm settings if they are hovering over the element. The problem happens that when it is not being hovered, it is set to false, and my last element in the map will always take president. I'm not sure how to approach this so that they all share the state of isHover.

```
const hoveredElement = (ctx, mouseOver, element, setIsHover) => {
  if ( mouseOver.x > element.x + 93 && mouseOver.x < element.x + 107 && mouseOver.y > element.y - 75 && mouseOver.y < element.y + 75) { // hovered right
    setIsHover(true);
  } else {
    setIsHover(false);
  }
}
```

This is a small example of my `hoveredElement` function (I'm checking on the edge of the element only in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use state just like other things. What you need to do is check if any element is hovered and toggle the state.

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useCallback,
  useMemo
} from "react";
import "./style.css";

let canvasWidth = 200;
let canvasHeight = 200;

export function useCanvas(w, h, props) {
  let ref = useRef();
  let elem = (
    <canvas ref={ref} width={canvasWidth} height={canvasHeight} {...props} />
  );

  let draw = useCallback(
    (box, color) => {
      let c = ref.current;
      let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.w);
    },
    [w, h]
  );

  let clear = useCallback(() => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  }, []);

  return [elem, draw, clear];
}

function getMousePos(e) {
  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: e.clientX - rect.left,
    y: e.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function isOverABox(box, mousePos) {
  return (
    mousePos.x >= box.x &&
    mousePos.y >= box.y &&
    mousePos.x <= box.x + box.w &&
    mousePos.y <= box.y + box.w
  );
}

export default function App() {
  let [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  let [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([
    { x: 5, y: 5, w: 10 },
    { x: 170, y: 80, w: 10 },
    { x: 80, y: 170, w: 10 }
  ]);

  let [canvas, draw, clear] = useCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasWidth, {
    onMouseMove: e => {
      let pos = getMousePos(e);
      let isHovered = boxes.some(b => isOverABox(b, pos));
      if (isHovered) setHovered(true);
      else setHovered(false);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let color = hovered ? "gold" : "black";
    boxes.forEach(b => draw(b, color));
  }, [boxes, draw, hovered]);
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        <code>hovered: {hovered ? "true" : "false"}</code>
      </pre>
      {canvas}
    </div>
  );
}
```

See the [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n2ezug).